# Jeremiah 29:6 - encouragement of intermarriage?

Tags: tanach, chutz-laaretz, literalism, intermarriage, yirmiyahu--book-of

It is [written](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jeremiah.29.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) to take wives and husbands, and then in the next verse to think of the welfare of the city where the Jews reside. Is it possible to see from here an encouragement of mixed marriage?

I am interested both in the historical question and the halachic one

Comment: This does not point to anything that implies encouragement of intermarriage. In fact it would seem to discourage intermarriage because that would mitigate against the peace of the city to which you were exiled.

Comment: If you're looking for a modern academic analysis, you may find something like kb.osu.edu/dspace/bitstream/handle/1811/58802/HAR_v14_121.pdf relevant. Intermarriage was more of a post-exilic concern. Historically, Jeremiah may well be opposed to it, I am not qualified to comment. The verse itself doesn't specify. If you're looking for the traditional Jewish explanation which is generally the approach of this platform, the assumption of total scriptural consistency would mean he's not supporting intermarriage

Answer (score 2):

How do you see a hint at intermarriage?

Yirmiyahu is encouraging the Jewish people to keep building Klal Yisrael through marriage, even though they are in exile.
Don't despair, since eventually they'll come back to israel.
(This would seem to be in contrast to what Amram [Moshe's father] initially held, when he decided that it was better to divorce his wife than father children who would be killed by Par'oh.)

I don't see any indication of intermarriage here.
And since we known intermarriage is forbidden, and in fact Ezra worked hard at removing the foreign wives when they came back to Israel, why would we assume Yirmiyahu was encouraging it?